# Struts2 conversation plugin

Tags: struts2, conversation-scope

Anyone has successfully used [Struts conversation plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/)?

The documentation says that fields annotated with `@ConversationField` annotation in Action class is supposed to be retained for the entire conversation, which is not happening.

Can you help me with any other plugin for Struts 2 for developing wizard-like application?

Following is my structure of struts.xml

```
<package name="wstest" namespace="/wstest" extends="struts-conversation-default"> 
  <action name="*" class="com.bla.bla.WebServiceTestController" method="{1}"> 
     <result name="upload">/WEB-INF/content/wstest/UploadWSDL.jsp</result> 
     <result name="selectoperation">
       /WEB-INF/content/wstest/selectoperation.jsp
     </result>
 </action> 
</package>
```

Comment: Show your configuration. If you need to create wizard take a look at ActionFlow plugin - https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-actionflow.

Comment: How it is not working? Any exceptions?

Comment: No exception, just unable to retain values accross the requests. However am switching my implementation to use ActionFlow plugin. Just quick question does is address bookmarking issue? i.e. if someone bookmarks any intermediate page and try to start the application does it redirect the user to begin page?

Comment: It depends. Do you want it to behave in that way?